# SQL View statement with 2 INNER JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Can anyone help me with this issue I tried many times but still haven't found the solution 
Here is the original View that I have in my database but now I made changes in the database and the view need to be changed also.

Here is the view as it was:

```
SELECT 
    [tableN].*, 
    [tabB].[att1] AS tabB_email, [tabB].[name] AS tabB_name,
    [tabC].[name] AS tabC_name
FROM  
    [tabC] 
INNER JOIN 
    ([tableN] 
INNER JOIN [tabB] ON [tableN].[sender_id] = [tabB].[ID]) 
     ON [tabC].[ID] = [tableN].[recipient_id]
```

Here is what is the difficult point for me. Now I don't have this 2 tables `tabB` and `tabC`

They are now in one table `tabX` and have an identifier field `roleId`. I manage to get all the columns except the last one `[tabC].[name] AS tabC_name`

Any ideas?

Comment: remvoe ` [tabC].[name] ` and remove `tabc` in from caluse change tabb to tabx

Comment: But i need the tabC_name witch is the same field as tabB_name but now have diferent id and roleID. Need to show that name

Comment: Could you please SQLFiddle the table schema? Or provide table structure with its relationship in your question?

Comment: I had tables Notif_Email(tableN)  , Developers(tabB), and Producers(tabC). Now I merge the tables Developers and Producers in one table Users(tableX) In the view I need to display the names od the developers and producers but now the are in one table Users just have different roleID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT [TableN].*, Bd.[email] AS bd_email, Bd.[showname] AS bd_name,
        Pc.[showname] AS pc_name
   FROM 
      [TABLE_X] AS Pc 
         INNER JOIN ([TableN] 
         INNER JOIN [TABLE_X]  AS Bd
         ON [TableN].[sender_id] = Bd.[ID] AND Bd.roleID = 1) 
         ON Pc.[ID] = [TableN].[recipient_id] AND Pc.roleID = 2
```

I finally find the the code that is working as needed

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT [tableN].*, [Tabx] .[att1] AS tabB_email, [Tabx] .[name] AS tabB_name  

  FROM  [Tabx] A 

  INNER JOIN [TABLEN] B

  ON A.ROLEID=B.RECIPIENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT [tableN].*, [tabX].[att1] AS tabB_email, [tabX].[name] AS tabB_name, 
t1.[name] AS tabC_name 
FROM [tabX] as t INNER JOIN ([tableN] INNER JOIN [tabX] 
ON [tableN].[sender_id] = [tabX].[roleid]) 
ON t.[roleid] = [tableN].[recipient_id]
```

Comment: `[tabB]` doesn't exist.

Comment: @RuslanVeselov now check it

Comment: I got the columns names but no data :/